# Templating engine without a backend?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I'm building a very simple, entirely front end app for a class and I need a JS templating engine. I want to generate HTML elements from a JSON file, and I want to use partials from separate files. Ideally I'd prefer to use vanilla JS and no jQuery.

I've been looking into Mustache, Handlebars, EJS and several others, but the options are overwhelming and I just want something simple.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Did you consider doing it in plain html without any templating engine?

Comment: if you're looking for simple: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Go straight the "The four finalists section" where you can find pros and cons for each.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has support for rendering templates with its template string backticks:

```
`${renderme}`
```

Here is a fully functional system using JavaScript as the templating engine in a few lines of code.

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
import template from './template.html?raw'

const params = ["name", `return \`${template}\``]
const templateFunction = new Function(...params)

const app = document.querySelector('#app')
app.innerHTML = templateFunction("World")
```

template.html

```
<h2>Hello ${name}!</h2>
```

Notice: the embedded backticks via backslashes in the second entry of the `params` array which only evaluate during the function call as they are part of the `return` statement's expression.

Renders:

```
Hello World!
```

Warning: the `Function` creation `eval`s the last argument as the function body so this is just a pretty face on the ugliness, slowness and dangerousness of eval, so don't let any user code get near the `params`.

https://playcode.io/1748931